# VBA: Use of "On Error" when calling a sub in another workbook,

Tags: excel, vba, onerror

I am building a process capable of sequentially launching and running subroutines in other multiple Excel workbooks. This is controlled by a 'master' batch launcher.

If there is *any* error in any one of these spreadsheets being run, the launcher needs to quit the run of *that* workbook and move onto the next workbook in the batch. **This process must be continuous without user input, so any error dialogue boxes need to be suppressed.**

Simplified to its core essence, my code is as such:

```
For I = 1 To NumberOfSubsToRun

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    Application.Run (SpreadsheetName & "!SubName")

ErrorHandler:

Next I
```

Some of the workbooks are falling over (not a problem), but they are creating an error dialogue box, stopping the batch in its tracks. The process seems to *forget* all about the *On Error* code in the launcher when it's running the called subroutine.

I am not allowed to change the code in the workbooks. If they fall over, they fall over. The launcher, somehow, needs to get around this problem on its own.

**Is there a way of 'reminding' the called subroutines about the On Error? Thus, if there was an error in any workbook sub, it would genuinely move on to the next workbook?**

Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, if you use `Run`, your `On Error` statement has no effect.

Comment: Try this: Instead of using Subs, call Functions. Error handlers in the individual functions can return an error number as the function return, so your main routine is informed.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg: OP is not allowed to change any of the functions in the workbooks.

Comment: **If** you can set references to the other workbooks (you'll need to be able to rename their projects to something other than the default VBAProject) then  you can call their routines directly without using `Run`.

Comment: @Bathsheba Darn, I missed that.  Thanks for catching the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

There's no easy way around this unfortunately: tighter scoped "On Error" declarations take precedence, and the `Run` method uses some non-VBA code under the hood which effectively blocks the error propagation.

But one solution would be to build your launcher in VBScript. You could then control the start-up of Excel, setting the application to not be visible. That ought to hide any message boxes that would otherwise appear.

Then could also argue that after a certain amount of time the process for a particular workbook has failed, and deal with that accordingly.

With sufficient out-of-process control, this solution will be remarkably stable. (I have something similar in my firm.)